# Which commonly available UV light source to use with fluorescein

Tags: fluorescence

I want to start experimenting with fluorescein.  I have a 353 nm UV light source, but am thinking that it might be too short since it looks like peak excitation occurs at 494 nm.  So am I correct in assuming that I should buy light sources that emit light at around 494 nm (480 nm for example)?

Comment: 494 nm is not ultra-violet.It is in the blue region. So you don't need an UV source to start experimenting with fluorescence. A purple or blue light would do the job. A source at 480 nm is OK.

Comment: You have to first look at the excitation spectrum of fluorescein. Where is the peak maximum? You would rather avoid UV due to safety reasons.

Comment: Some blue or white LED source could be good enough.

Comment: Your UV source should be fine. If not there are plenty of near-visble UV, low output sources (widely used for revealing the UV security marks in banknotes) and there are even cheap, low power near-visible UV handheld laser pointers or LED sources.

Comment: BTW, if you use a blue or indigo light source, look through a yellow filter to greatly increase contrast - it blocks blue, but lets yellow-green fluorescence trhough.

Comment: This page shows the spectra https://omlc.org/spectra/PhotochemCAD/html/010.html so you can see that 353 nm is a poor wavelength to use. 450 nm ish would be better, selected with an interference filter and an arc or tungsten lamp would be simplest otherwise find some Wratten filters or of course a 450 nm diode laser.